# Get non-repeated characters in string and count them

Tags: php, string, filtering, counting, non-repetitive

I need to process a string like `abclkjabc` and return only `3` which counts characters `l`, `k`, and `j`.

I've tried this.

```php
$stringArr = [];
foreach(str_split($string) as $pwd) {
   if(!in_array($pwd, $stringArr)) {
      $stringArr[] = $pwd;
   }
}
$uniqChar = count($stringArr);
```

Comment: I'm guessing what you consider the repeating string can have an arbitary length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
function getNonRepeatingCharacters($str) {
    $counter = [];
    $spllitted = str_split($str);
    foreach($spllitted as $s) {
        if(!isset($counter[$s])) $counter[$s] = 0;
        $counter[$s]++;
    }
    $non_repeating = array_keys(array_filter($counter, function($c) {
        return $c == 1;
    }));

    return $non_repeating;
}

$string = "abclkjabc";
$handle = getNonRepeatingCharacters($string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Functional programming and no temporary variable declarations:

1. Create an array of characters
2. Count the occurrences of each character
3. Retain only characters that occurred once (`array_filter()` also works but is more verbose)
4. Re-join the qualifying characters

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/qWQju)) ([or just the count](https://3v4l.org/t0CnY))

```
echo implode(
         array_keys(
             array_intersect(
                 array_count_values(
                     str_split('abclkjabc'),
                 ),
                 [1]
             )
         )
     );
```

Or with semi-functional with a loop: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/XBS5K)) ([or just the count](https://3v4l.org/c1RlR))

```
$unique = '';
foreach (array_count_values(str_split('abclkjabc')) as $char => $count) {
    if ($count === 1) {
        $unique .= $char;
    }
}
echo $unique;
```

Output:

```
lkj
```

Getting the length of the output string can be done with `strlen()`.

---

Instead of splitting the string and count array values, you can count character values with `count_chars()`. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/r4sFE))

```
$string = 'abclkjabc';
$notRepeated = [];
foreach (count_chars($string, 1) as $char => $count) {
    if ($count === 1) {
        $notRepeated[] = chr($char);
    }
}
var_export($notRepeated);
echo "\nCount = " . count($notRepeated);
```

---

Ultimately, if you only need the count of non-repeated characters, this one-liner will get you there. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Mpcec))

```
echo count(array_filter(count_chars($string, 1), fn($count) => $count === 1));
```

Comment: @rustiana is my answer incorrect? Or is this just a continued attack from one of my latest "fans" that Stack Overflow hasn't managed to ban from the site yet?

Comment: To improve the clarity of your question, do you actually need to know the string that contains the unique characters? or only the count?

Comment: I actually need to know both, string that contains the unique and the count.

Comment: I've extended my answer after it was no-comment attacked again (as part of a serial dv spree against my account).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getNonRepeatingChars($str) {
    $uniqueLetters = '';
    $multipleLetters = '';
    $arrayStr = str_split($str);

    foreach ($arrayStr as $index => $letter) {
        if (strpos($multipleLetters, $value) !== false || strpos($str, $value, $index + 1) !== false) {
            $multipleLetters .= $value;
            continue;
        }

        $uniqueLetters .= $value;
    }

    return $uniqueLetters;
}
```

```
echo getNonRepeatingChars('abclkjabc'); // lkj
```